# Is there a better way to instantiate a constant with generic maths?

Tags: c#, templates, generics, math

I'm experimenting with the new [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) support in .NET 7 and am trying to figure out if there is a better way to express constants that are not 1 or 0. In the function below I am able to construct 9, but it's *clearly* far from ideal...

```
public static T DigitalRoot<T>(T value) where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
    var x = T.Abs(value: value);
    var y = T.Min(x: x, y: T.One);
    var z = (T.One + T.One + T.One + T.One + T.One + T.One + T.One + T.One + T.One);

    return (y + ((x - y) % z));
}
```

Comment: `(T.One + T.One + T.One) * (T.One + T.One + T.One)` is a bit shorter, but I agree, still not ideal.

Comment: or `(T.One << 3) + T.One`

Comment: How about `T.CreateChecked(9)`? See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createchecked?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-inumberbase-1-createchecked-1(-0)).

Comment: @MvG. This should be an answer.

Comment: Make your class generic (instead of the method) and declare what comes closest to a constant: `private static readonly T Nine = T.CreateChecked(9);`

Comment: If you're looking for *compile-time* constants that might be worth calling out more explicitly. For C# I don't know how much of this is specified at the language level, i.e. whether there is anything that says compilers must turn your 1+1…1 expression into a single constant, or forbids them from evaluating `CreateChecked` at compile-time.

Comment: @MvG Sorry, I thought my comment had been deleted quickly enough. Was my fault for accidentally declaring a property instead of a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a `static readonly` field and initialize it with `T.CreateChecked(9)` as suggested by @MvG. This comes close to a constant:

```cs
internal static class BinaryIntegerConstants<T> where T : IBinaryInteger<T>
{
    public static readonly T Nine = T.CreateChecked(value: 9);
}

public static class UncategorizedFunctions
{
    public static T DigitalRoot<T>(this T value) where T : IBinaryInteger<T>
    {
        var x = T.Abs(value: value);
        var y = T.Min(x: x, y: T.One);
        var z = BinaryIntegerConstants<T>.Nine;

        return y + ((x - y) % z);
    }
}
```

Test:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(15.DigitalRoot());
```

Note: the idea to extract the constants to a separate class and to turn the method into an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) was brought in by @Kittoes0124.